# Forma correta de trabalhar com composer no php

Tags: php, composer

Olá, gosto bastante de php e a algum tempo estou utilizando o conceito de MVC em minha aplicação, porém sem utilizar o composer e seu autoloader. Em busca de elevar meu conhecimento, instalei o mesmo e cheguei a usar aplicações de terceiros utilizando as dependências.

A dúvida é: onde a MINHA aplicação fica?

Li que precisa adicionar o seguinte código no meu composer.json

```
    "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {"MeuProjeto\\": "src/"}
    }
```

Porém ainda assim não funciona, utilizei os comandos:

> composer update | composer dump-autoload

e não funcionou, qual seria o problema? o erro que dá é esse:

> Fatal error: Class 'Init' not found in C:\inetpub\Estudo\public\index.php on line 33

Porém utilizando as aplicações inclusas nas dependencias do projeto (dentro da pasta vendor) não ocorre tal erro
obrigado

Comment: Você está utilizando o `namespace MeuProjeto;` na classe `Init`? Sua classe está dentro da pasta `src/MeuProjeto`? Sua aplicação fica na pasta `src`, mas caso você instale como uma dependência, a aplicação fica normalmente em `vendor/author_user/package_name/src/namespace/*.php`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr rapaz, num é que esqueci de definir o namespace? pois o arquivo Init.php não era em si um namespace, era o arquivo inicial de acesso que ai sim redirecionava para o devido namespace... obrigado!

Comment: E não, eu adicionei o código que encontrei na documentação do composer para minha aplicação ficar na pasta src (para minha organização)

Comment: Blz. Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Consegui sim amigão, obrigado a ajuda!